# Find which PyCharm projects use a conda environment

Tags: pycharm, anaconda, conda

For a directory `/path/to/dir/`, which contains multiple PyCharm projects in an arbitrary directory hierarchy, how can I which (if any) PyCharm projects are using a specific conda environment, without opening them all, but doing it programmatically?

A sub-question would be, how to find out programmatically which conda environment a specific PyCharm project is using.

(My use is to be able to delete conda environments that are not used anymore, but I am sure there are other uses for this question as well.)

Comment: Are there any text configuration files in the directory? What does the directory structure with the PyCharm projects look like?

Comment: @darthbith: There is a folder `.idea` in which there are the files `misc.xml` and `workspace.xml` which seem to be relevant. I suspect that the file `misc.xml` is the relevant file, since it contains an entry `<component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" project-jdk-name="Python 3.6.2 (Anaconda-Python-Distribution/anaconda2/envs/analysis/bin/python3.6)" project-jdk-type="Python SDK" />` where `analysis` is my environment.

Comment: So you should be able to write a Python script that goes through those directories and extracts the environment name :-) I'm not sure if there are any existing tools to do this, but if you do develop your own, please post it here in case other people are interested :-)